# Parented object on imported FBX giving weird rotation data

Tags: armature, export, import, parent, .fbx

In the original mesh everything was zeroed out before parenting to the armature, and appears fine before export, but then when I import the model back into blender the parented object is giving weird rotations.[image: image of import .fbx model]